# Enumerize rails does not allow nil values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, backend, enumerize

I'm using the enumerize gem on my project, and when I add it into a column, in which I want to allow nil values, my test brokes up but not the insertion on the console.

```
MY_TYPES = ['foo',
            'baz',
            'bar'].freeze

enumerize :my_column, in: MY_TYPES,
                      default: nil,
                      scope: :shallow,
                      presence: false
```

When I try to add a nil value to `my_column`, the ActiveRecord validation appears:

```
*** ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid Exception: Validation failed: My tipes is not included in the list
```

But if I modify the value from the `rails console`, the nil value can be assigned without any trouble.

I've been tryin' with the `allow_blank: true`, `allow_nil: true` and lately with the `presence: false` option.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You say you can **assign** the `nil` value in the console, but that doesn't run validations. Can you then run `validate!` on the model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[As per the docs](https://github.com/brainspec/enumerize?tab=readme-ov-file#activerecord), an inclusion validation is added by default. You'd need to add `skip_validation` and then add the `allow_nil` inclusion validation yourself:

```rb
enumerize :my_column, in: MY_TYPES, skip_validations: true, ...
validates :my_column, inclusion: MY_TYPES, allow_nil: true
```

#### Update

I just noticed that you can also include a lambda, so you *should* (untested) be able to do this (without having to add the separate validation):

```rb
enumerize :my_column, in: MY_TYPES, skip_validations: -> { _1.my_column.nil? }
```